# How to create Embedding matrix by using TFIDF?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, recurrent-neural-network, word2vec, tf-idf

I had taken a Text dataset to predict the sentiment of review is positive or negative. By using TFIDF I had converted word to vectors. Next, I had loaded Glove Embedding pre-trained file. Now how to create Embedding Matrix using TFIDF and glove word embeddings? I want to use Embedding Matrix in my Recurrent Neural Network.

I am facing Index Error while creating Embedding matrix, please correct me if I did wrong anything in the coding part.

```
**TFIDF Vectorizer**
''' from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
    vectorizer_1 = TfidfVectorizer( max_features=10000,sublinear_tf=True, 
    use_idf=True,stop_words='english')
    X_vt = vectorizer_1.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_vt.shape
    (426340, 10000)'''
**Glove Embedding**
''' embedding_index = {}
    f = open(os.path.join(' ', 
    'C:/Users/User/glove.6B/glove.6B.100d.txt'),encoding="utf-8")
    for line in f:
      values=line.split()
      word = values[0]
      coefs = np.asarray(values[1:])
      embedding_index[word] = coefs
    f.close() '''

enter code here
''' emdedding_matrix = zeros((vocab_size,100))
 for feature, names in vectorizer_1.get_feature_items():
     embedding_vector = embedding_index.get(feature)
     if embedding_vector is not None:
        emdedding_matrix[names] = embedding_vector '''
```

[image: Error]

Comment: `names` is obviously of wrong type. Maybe calling `.items()`. Next type, can you please copy-paste your instead of a screenshot, so others can also copy-paste the code and try out directly.

Comment: @Jindřich I had edited my post, please check this